# SQL "expected DATE got NUMBER"

Tags: sql, oracle

When running the below script I get the error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER". Doesn't give me a line on which the error is at. Using Oracle DB.

```sql
with reg_det as (
SELECT MCI.MEASR_COMP_ID
FROM D1_MEASR_COMP_IDENTIFIER MCI, D1_MEASR_COMP_IDENTIFIER MCR, D1_MEASR_COMP MC, D1_DVC_CFG DC, D1_DVC_IDENTIFIER DVI
WHERE MCI.MC_ID_TYPE_FLG = 'D1EI'
AND MCI.MEASR_COMP_ID = MC.MEASR_COMP_ID
AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(MCI.ID_VALUE, '[^-]+', 1, 13) = 'INT'
AND MCR.MC_ID_TYPE_FLG = 'CMRN'
AND MCR.ID_VALUE = :REG
AND MCR.MEASR_COMP_ID = MC.MEASR_COMP_ID
AND MC.DEVICE_CONFIG_ID = DC.DEVICE_CONFIG_ID
AND DVI.D1_DEVICE_ID = DC.D1_DEVICE_ID
AND DVI.DVC_ID_TYPE_FLG = 'D1SN'
AND DVI.ID_VALUE = :MTR),
gap_dates as (select to_char((:SDTTM + level -1),'YYYY-MM-DD') as read_date, 0 as interval_count, 'M' as quality, 0 as daily_load
                                  from dual
                                  connect by level <= (:EDTTM - :SDTTM) )
,read_data as (SELECT to_char(trunc(MSRMT_DTTM - 1/1440),'YYYY-MM-DD') as read_date,
count(1) as interval_count,
case
  when min(msrmt_cond_flg) > 500000 THEN 'A'
    when min(msrmt_cond_flg) > 400000 and min(msrmt_cond_flg) <= 500000 then 'F'
    when min(msrmt_cond_flg) > 300000 and min(msrmt_cond_flg) <= 400000 then 'S'
    when min(msrmt_cond_flg) > 200000 and min(msrmt_cond_flg) <= 300000 then 'E'
    when min(msrmt_cond_flg) <= 200000 then 'M' end as quality,    
sum(msrmt_val) as daily_load FROM REG_DET REG, D1_MSRMT DATA
WHERE DATA.MEASR_COMP_ID = REG.MEASR_COMP_ID
AND MSRMT_DTTM > :SDTTM
AND MSRMT_DTTM <= (:EDTTM + 1)
GROUP BY trunc(MSRMT_DTTM - 1/1440))
select * from read_data
union
select * from gap_dates a where 1=1 and not exists (select 1 from read_data b where a.read_date = b.read_date);
```

Comment: Please don’t post images, use editable text so that someone can copy it if they want to try your code. Can you also update your question with the definitions of the tables used in your SQL. Also, you really ought to use ANSI SQL join syntax - the Oracle join syntax you are using hasn’t been considered good practice for decades.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates the issue; an explanation of the underlying problem you are trying to solve; and the expected output for that sample data. Also, please try to reduce the problem to a **MINIMAL** example and remove all the unnecessary columns from the table and query so it becomes easier to debug.

Comment: Please also [edit] the question to include details of how you are setting the bind variables and the values passed to the bind variables.

Comment: @M10, bind variables SDTTM&EDTTM in format YYYY-MM-DD 
REG is just a string of 2 characters: XX
MTR is a string as well: XXXXXXXX

Comment: if the bind variables are strings representing dates, you expect to be able to use them as numbers and add/subtract values from them? From you sql, I think you probably need to convert them to dates before, using to_date(:SDTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: @dohan_rivas Do not post updates in comments, [edit] your question. Also, you would do better to include the code where you set the bind variables as stating "SDTTM&EDTTM in format YYYY-MM-DD" does not tell us what data-type you are using for the bind variables `:SDTTM` & `:EDTTM` as they could be either strings (that just happen to look like dates) or dates. If they are strings then you should not get that error, you should get a different error as `'1970-01-01' + 1 - 1` will fail as you cannot use the addition operator with a string; and if they are dates then that part should work.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the code provided is impossible to check as we don't know the structure of your tables nor the datatypes of the columns. I tried to cut the code in pieces to do the tests, and the only part that is returning ORA-00932 error is **in the WHERE clause of the read_data cte**.
I'm not sure if that is your problem, but if it is it will not be the only one. What I wanted to say is that even if you correct this one there will be more errors. Let me explain - the reported error could be simulated if you bind a character value to your :EDTTM variable. Other errors would pop up if :SDTTM is of type character.
Here is the test using construction from the mentioned WHERE clause:

```sql
        WHERE 
            DATA.MEASR_COMP_ID = reg.MEASR_COMP_ID
            AND MSRMT_DTTM > :SDTTM     
            AND MSRMT_DTTM <= (:EDTTM + 1)
```

The last condition tested on DUAL table (assuming that MSRMT_DTTM is of type DATE) compares DATE to CHARACTER + NUMBER like in this SQL

```sql
SELECT 'anything' FROM DUAL WHERE SYSDATE <= '24-SEP-22' + 1
```

This results with:

```sql
/*
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*/
```

If any or both of your %DTTM variables are of type character then there will be more errors (not ORA-00932) throughout your code. Additionaly, you should really consider the advice form comments to use ANSI SQL join syntax. Regards...